# __int64 для COM Automation?

Tags: com, типы

Известно что в COM Automation Types не поддерживается тип:

```
IDL type    Variant type    OLEAutomation   Description 
__int64     VT_I8           No              8-byte signed integer
```

Можно было бы использовать double (VT_R8) так как никаких математических операций не предполагается только функции get_value \ set_value:

```
IDL type    Variant type    OLEAutomation   Description 
double      VT_R8           Yes             8-byte real
```

Но есть опасения что если нужно будет выводить эти значения в файл или на печать то преобразовать в __int64 это будет весьма проблематично в каком то JScript\VBScript. С другой стороны использовать строки какое то корявое решение в данном случае.

Какой выход в данном случае?

Comment: Является ли поддержка `JScript\VBScript` обязательным условием? Скажем, `powershell` в плане COM-взаимодействия умеет куда больше, хоть оно и глубже запрятано

Comment: Да, - является.

Answer (score 1):

Если нет типа нужно длинны, нужно собрать его из более мелких подходящих. Насколько я знаю, Variant умеет тип Byte, который соответствует unsgined char. Т.е. можно использовать 8 байтов, а уж собрать тип на целевой платформе - дело техники: сдвиговые и побитовые операции есть, [пожалуй](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378246/bit-shift-when-there-is-no-bit-shift-operator), [везде](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Comment: И как этот тип из нескольких Byte представляется в IDL? Или предлагаете делать новый интерфейс с 8-ми методами (SetFirstByte, SetSecondByte, ...)? P.S. Этот вариант еще менее удобен чем строка.

Comment: Та же есть Array: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee267517%28v=bts.10%29.aspx ? Жаль, конечно, что не поддерживается беззнаковые UI4, тогда бы достаточно было пары I4+UI4.

Comment: SafeArray это адовый трэш для такой легкой задачи. Выходит что строка наименьшее зло.

Comment: Не, ну можно и двумя VT_I4 и одним VT_I1 обойтись. А так, получается, что да.